# Meteor-Files thumbnail link

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am following this tutorial, https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/wiki/Image-Processing

I am successful on creating thumbnails.
I am successful on adding versions in the collection.

I want to display the thumbnail. My problem now is how can I get link for `<img>` tag?

For the original image, I used `FilesCollection.link(fileRef)`.

How can I do it same in thumbnails?

I am using Veliov meteor-files package and GraphicMagick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, I think. Just to verify, there is a code snippet in the thumbnail generation that looks like this:

```
const upd = { $set: {} };
upd['$set']['versions.thumbnail'] = fileRef.versions.thumbnail;
```

This means that in the fileObj for the main file, there is a property named "versions" which now has a sub-property named "thumbnail".

Reading through the code, I find that you can access this from the main fileObj thus:

```
fileObj.link('thumbnail')
```

I have verified that this works. If you add other versions, I'm sure they work the same way.

Comment: I already solved this problem long time ago. But only for thumbnail, didn't test it with other versions. Thanks for confirmation.

Comment: I suspected that you had, but since I couldn't find anything about it, I thought it would be nice to have the answer up on SE.